ERROR There are no commands defined in the "install" namespace
i am using laravel 10.48.14 and whenever i want to run "php artisan install:api , it gives me the error
ERROR  There are no commands defined in the "install" namespace.

Does the command show up in php artisan? Are you certain it's Laravel11? What does php artisan about output?

sorry i found that it is laravel 10.48.14 but how can i install api

That command should work. Can you confirm the version of Laravel you are using?

You don't need to install the api in Laravel 10. You should automatically have an api.php for endpoints. You can install sanctum for API token authentication

The command you are using is for Laravel 11. For Laravel 10.x, you can find your API enpoints in routes/api.php. To use an authenication token for your API scaffolding, you need to install Scantum. You can use the command:
composer require laravel/sanctum

You can read more about Laravel 10 Sanctum here.
